# How to Convert a*b-c*d in c++ expression

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and i got an assignment, to convert a*b-c*d into c++ expression
Here is my Code Line

```html
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 int a,b,c,d,e,f ,sum;
 cout<<"enter value of A";
 cin>>a;
 cout<<"enter value of b";
 cin>>b;
 cout<<"Your Answer is";
 cin>>a*b=e;
 cout<<"enter value of c";
 cin>>a;
 cout<<"enter value of d";
 cin>>b;
 cout<<"Your Answer is";
 cin>>c*d=f;
 cin>>e-f;
 sum=e-f;
    getch();
}
```

Your Help 'll be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You do not get values assigned to c or d. Re-read your code!

Comment: cout<<"enter value of c ";
 cin>>c;
 cout<<"enter value of d ";
 cin>>d;
 cout<<"Your Answer is ";
 cout<<a*b-c*d<<endl;

Comment: `cin>>a*b=e;` Explain to us what this is supposed to do.

Comment: note that you use cin for input stream. so cin>>a*b=e wont work. so just assign e as e = a*b instead of cin>>a*b=e. Similarly for 'cin>>c*d=f'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed some of the things you are trying to do assuming you are using e and f as temporary variables to calculate ab-cd, and sum as the final variable.

```
            #include<iostream>
            #include<conio.h>
            #include<stdio.h>
            using namespace std;
            int main ()
            {
                int a,b,c,d,e,f ,sum;
                cout<<"enter value of A";
                cin>>a;
                cout<<"enter value of b";
                cin>>b;
                cout<<"Your Answer is";
                e = a*b;
                cout<<"enter value of c";
                cin>>c;
                cout<<"enter value of d";
                cin>>d;
                cout<<"Your Answer is";
                f = c*d;
                sum=e-f;
                cout << sum;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks your editing worked perfect. This shows i need bit more practice, i was near with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a,b,c,d,e,f ,sum;
    cout<<"enter value of A";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"enter value of b";
    cin>>b;
    e=a*b;
    cout<<"Your Answer is"<<e<<endl;

    cout<<"enter value of c";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"enter value of d";
    cin>>b;
    f=c*d;
    cout<<"Your Answer is"<<f<<end;

    sum=e-f;
    getch();
}
```

You use cin statement to get input from user, the evaluation is not done in cin statement, consider this code if it works for you.